# PrimeNg Autocomplete sends empty string on clear

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

I have a p-autocomplete element (primeng 7.0.5) that controls a custom object field (type OrganizationView).

Here is the markup:

```
<p-autoComplete
    [(ngModel)]="state.organization"
    (completeMethod)="onSearchOrganisation($event)"
    (onClear)="state.organization = null"
    (onSelect)="onOrganizationSelected($event)"
    [emptyMessage]="'GLOBALS.NORESULT' | translate"
    [forceSelection]="true"
    [suggestions]="availableOrganizations"
    [dropdown]="true"
    field="name"
    placeholder="{{'PLACEHOLDERS.ORGANISATION' | translate}}">
```

The state.organization triggers a setter with the following code:

```
set organization(newOrganization: OrganizationView) {
    this._organization = newOrganization;
    console.log(typeof newOrganization, newOrganization);
  }
```

When selecting values from the auto complete, I always get OrganizationView objects, as expected. The problem appears on clearing the field:

When clearing (select all with mouse and press backspace), my setter is triggered 2 times: one with null and the second with an empty string. Here is the console.log output:

```
> object null
> string
```

The insertion of the string concerns me because it messes up the whole strong-typed system that I try to setup. I can write explicit checks for empty strings, but I was wondering if there is a more clean solution, or if I got something wrong.

Comment: Hello, I am curious how did you end up handling this?  I am running into a similar issue right now and expecting the value to be null but it is an empty string

Comment: Hello Tommo. Unfortunatelly, I had to give up to any clean solution. I explicitly checked for empty string (via === operator), and convert it to null before proceeding.
Maybe they have fixed the bug, though. I am not working on that project anymore. Sorry, I would like to offer some better solution than that...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and use this workaround :

```
set organization(newOrganization: OrganizationView) {
    this._organization = newOrganization ? newOrganization : <OrganizationView>{};
    console.log(typeof newOrganization, newOrganization);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. A workaround is to remove the data binding and just use the onClear and onComplete events to set/clear the field.

```
<p-autoComplete
    <!-- [(ngModel)]="state.organization" remove this binding-->
    (completeMethod)="onSearchOrganisation($event)"
    (onClear)="state.organization = null"
    (onSelect)="onOrganizationSelected($event)"
    [emptyMessage]="'GLOBALS.NORESULT' | translate"
    [forceSelection]="true"
    [suggestions]="availableOrganizations"
    [dropdown]="true"
    field="name"
    placeholder="{{'PLACEHOLDERS.ORGANISATION' | translate}}">
```

You can also use the select method like

```
(onSelect)="state.organization = $event"
```

if you won't do anything extra in the .ts file